# Subtract two times of day to get interval length in hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am working on creating Time sheet in excel and i have the format like this.

```
 A            B        C         D          E      F
Date         Day    Time IN    Time OUT   Lunch   Total
8/29/2011    Monday   9.00       18.00     0.45    8.55
```

I am not able to get correct hours in Total field. Correct value should have been 8.15 and not 8.55.

This is the current formula i am using in to calculate Total.

```
=D2-C2-E2
```

Can someone please help me get the formula right?

Comment: That's to be expected, when the fields are formatted as numbers. You'd have to format them as time values to get "8 hours 15 minutes" instead of a standard floating ponit 8.55.

Comment: Don't forget to use special format [h]:mm if you want hours > 23 to be displayed - especially in time totals. Happy time-sheeting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of typing e.g. `9.00` in your cells, type `9:00` (and format your cells as time to make sure they display correctly).

The formula itself is fine, but currently you're just subtracting decimal numbers, and of course the correct result is 8.55.

Comment: And prefix your minutes-only times with zero to get the same effect.  0:45 for 45 minutes.